# Search with a Database Locator on a single column with correct confidence?

Tags: database, ocr, kofax

I've been using Kofax Transformation Modules for 3 years and I'm still not sure how the Database Locator works.

I have a very simple database, with a bunch of columns.
I have a very simple PDF document, OCR is done.

I want to retrieve one record from the database, based on the value of a single column.
So if a value from this column is found on the document, I want the database locator to return the corresponding record, with 100% confidence (or whatever the OCR confidence is for this single value).

And last but not least, I want this confidence to work with the "minimum confidence" I set in the database locator's properties (general tab).

But it doesn't seem possible.
See, my PDF document contains a value, read by OCR, that is a 100% match for the database column.
The locator returns the record with a so-called 100% confidence, since I set the search mask on that single column.

But if I put the minimum confidence to anything higher than 34%, the record is not returned.

Why is that? How can it be fixed?
Do I really have to use a script locator to do what I want, which doesn't seem that complicated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unintuitive Confidence Value

When the Database Locator runs, it tries to find find records that best match the document OCR.  The key to the behavior you see is that it first does the *actual* fuzzy search, returning records that meet the minimum confidence, and *then* the locator itself does additional processing: increasing or decreasing the confidence of records depending on whether they meet the Fields, Search Masks, or Regions settings defined in the locator.

The up side to this behavior is memory and processing efficiency.  The core fuzzy search index can quickly determine which records that meet the initial confidence threshold, then the Database Locator only needs to load those into memory and do the post processing.  The alternative would be that all records would need to be loaded to do post processing just in case the post processing pushed the confidence above the threshold. That would be more intuitive, but less efficient.

### Possible Configuration Improvement

If you only intend to search on that one column, and the other columns are just data you want returned, then make sure that column is the only one indexed.  When you open the properties of the database, it shows the field names with checkboxes.  Any fields that are checked are indexed and are part of what the locator will try to find on the document.  You could be getting lower confidence if you have a bunch of fields checked that aren't actually on the document, especially if you also have a non-zero value for the locator setting "Penalty for empty fields".

When using KSMS, the indexed columns cannot be changed in Project Builder since KSMS is building and serving the index. Instead open the Import Settings of the database within KSMS Administration and see that there is a "Columns to Use" section of checkboxes. If you configured the database by uploading a file rather than pointing to a UNC path, you will need to upload it again to be able to change which columns were indexed.

### Context

**For anyone reading this as a traditional database question:** A "database" in this context in KTM takes records from CSV or relational database and indexes them for fuzzy matching.  This core fuzzy search functionality is used in a few ways, one of which is the Database Locator.

**Documentation mentioning Database Locator processing separately from fuzzy search:**
The scripting help topic "Database Lookup in Specific Columns" shows how to use the fuzzy search from script (From a script window: Help>Scripting Help, then Script Samples > Database Lookup in Specific Columns), but it also has some mention of the fuzzy search itself as separate from some of the other settings handled by the Database Locator.

Comment: How do I define my database indexes? The database is indeed a CSV file (through KSMS), I don't see where the indexing happens.

Comment: Ah yes, same concept in a different place when using a KSMS database.  I've updated the answer for KSMS.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some more insights to Stephan's already great answer. First of all, there are some known issues with the Database Locator (DBL) and the minimum confidence when search masks are being used. We have no definite explanation for that, but we observed the DBL can miss records that have a higher confidence then the one returned, especially when working with millions of records in the index. We searched for a customer id once, and set the threshold to .8, and the number of records returned 100. The DBL returned records within a range of .8 and .98, but not the final record that definitely was there. Increasing the minimum confidence to 1 did yield it, though.

In addition, here's how confidences in the Database Locator are being calculated. First of all, let's look at the weights present in the DBL:

- Must exist: 1.8
- High: 1.4
- Normal: 1
- Low: 0.6
- Very low: 0.2

Each subfield's confidence is then being multiplied by the weight. Let's say the DBL found the first name with a confidence of 1, and you said it would be "very important" - the weighted confidence value is 1.8. This is repeated for each subfield, and the final confidence of the record is the sum product of all confidences and weights.

Here's an example: let's assume four subfields with different weights. Let's also assume that our DBL found confident matches for first and last names (with the first name being at 95%, the last name at 100%); and there's a confident hit for the city, but not the zip code:

```
                        First Name   Street   Zip    City  
 --------------------- ------------ -------- ------ ------ 
  Importance (weight)   1.4             1.4    0.2    0.2  
  Confidence            0.95              1    0.2      1  
  weighted Confidence   1.33            1.4   0.04    0.2  
  --                                                       
  TOTAL:                93%
```

The total confidence for the record is 0.93, here's how it was calculated:

```
(1.33 + 1.4 + 0.04 + 0.2 ) / (1.4 + 1.4 + 0.2 + 0.2) = 0.928125
```